# A question in abstract algebra , extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $K$ be the field generated by the elements $e^{2πi/n}$   $(n=1,2,\dotsc)$.
Show that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic extension but that $[K : \mathbb{Q}]$ is not finite.

I know that the minimal polynomial of $e^{2πi/p}$ for a prime $p$ is $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dots+1$, but I don't see how this can help me.

Comment: What does $Q$ denote?  The field of rational numbers?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Your elements are roots of 1. Then recall that the degree of your extension essentially counts how Big a Vector space it is over Q.

Comment: Suppose instead that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n<+\infty$. Can you obtain a contradiction?

Comment: Can i say that $\zeta_n$ =$e^{2πi/n}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^n-1$ which means that it is a root of: $(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)...$ ? @Caffeine , I'm not sure

Comment: @Almaa You can, but I do not see how that could be useful. Instead, I suggest you derive a contradiction by analizing $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)\subset K$, where $p$ is a prime number bigger than $n+1$

Comment: But @Caffeine how to show that it is an algebraic extension? I have to find a polynomial that $\zeta$ is its root

Comment: @Almaa Given a base field $K$ and $\alpha$ an algebraic element over $K$, $K(\alpha)$ is algebraic

Comment: @Caffeine can you write a proof for this? , it will be more clear

Comment: @Almaa let $n$ be the degree of the minimal polynomial$f\in K[x]:f(\alpha)=0$. Then we have $K(\alpha)\simeq \frac{K(x)}{(f)}$, and its easy to see that its dimension over $K$ is $\text{deg}(f)=n$. Thus, $K(\alpha)$ is a finite extension, and so it's algebraic. This result, however, is standard, and you can find it at the beginning of any book on Galois theory

Comment: @Caffeine Thank you , that's right, but the second part of the question was not obvious to me!

Comment: @Almaa as I said in my first comment, the second part can be solved by finding a contradiction assuming $[K:\mathbb{Q}]<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is irreducible. If $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$ and $\alpha$ is a root in some extension field $F$, then $F\supseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=k
$$
Thus, if $F$ is a finite extension, $[F:\mathbb{Q}]\ge k$.

Can you finish?

Further hint: if $p$ is prime and $\alpha\ne1$ is a $p$-th root of $1$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=p-1$. Are prime numbers bounded?

Comment: I understand this theory..but could not accomplish it in this question @egreg

Comment: @Almaa How many primes are there?

Comment: I don't understand your question unfortunately @egreg ,but i would be glad if you can explain for me how it is connected to the question

Comment: @Almaa If $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=m$ is finite, then no complex $p$-th root of $1$ can belong to $K$, if $p>m$.

Comment: @egreg I think you meant $p>m+1$, since $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p):\mathbb{Q}]=p-1$

Comment: @Caffeine Yes, right. Too late to fix, but the idea should be clear anyway.

Comment: @egreg sorry i was not concentrated enough when u asked me how many prime numbers exist, of course there are infinite prime numbers..so that's why u can assume that p>m+1 , in contadiction to our assume that m>p-1 if K/Q algebraic , right? Thanks

Comment: @Almaa Yes, that's the idea: $K$ contains extensions of unbounded degree.